# Service Stack : How do I post DateTime with jQuery

Tags: servicestack

Suppose I have a request DTO that looks like this:

```
public class MyRequest
{
    public DateTime? SomeDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

And on the client I want to post to it using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url : '/myrequest',
    data: { someDateTime: new Date() },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { console.log(data.success); }
});
```

Why does this **not** work? `MyRequest.SomeDateTime` is never populated. What should I be passing instead of `new Date()`?

Answer (score 1):

Pass in

```
new Date().toJSON()
```

See [The "right" JSON date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format) for more information about dates in json